# UINavigationViewController calls root view controllers didMoveToParentViewController differently then pushed view controllers

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, uicontainerview

As per the apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didMoveToParentViewController),

`didMoveToParentViewController`:

> Called after the view controller is added or removed from a container view controller.
>   "parent" argument - The parent view controller, or nil if there is no parent.

Situation: **NavVC** --rootviewcontroller--> **VCOne** --Push--> **VCTwo**

Here if I override `didMoveToParentViewController` in VCOne and put break point on it, I notice that on pushing VCTwo, this method is called with `parent` as the `UINavigationController` object.
Existence of this non will object signifies addition of this child view controller to the container view. But VCOne has already been added as the child view controller this was not expected, nor it is being removed as the `parent` parameter is non nil.

**Question** : Why is didMoveToParentViewController being called on VCOne while pushing VCTwo, when it is already added as a child?

---

Also this unexpected call is seen only on the root view controller. If I extent the situation like

Situation: **NavVC** --rootviewcontroller--> **VCOne** --Push--> **VCTwo** --Push--> **VCThree**
I observe that `didMoveToParentViewController` is not being called on VCTwo when VCThree is pushed.

---

EDIT : Also observed that `willMoveToParentViewController` is never called on root view controller i.e VCOne.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: didMoveToParentViewController not called as per docs